# Running tensorflow_model_server from bash is throwing 'command not found error'

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving

I am running tensorflow server from bash:
Command used:

```
tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 --model_name=saved_model --model_base_path=$(<path to .pb file in my system>/saved_model.pb)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
<path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 1: $'\b\001\022\344\307\376\016': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 2: $'\203\020\022\345\017': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 4: $'\003Add\022\006': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 6: $'\001x\001T\022\006\n\001y\001T\032\006': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 7: $'\001z\001T\E': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 8: $'\001T\022\004type:\020': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 9: $'\0162\f\016\023\001\002\004\006\005\003': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 10: 8: command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 11: $'\004Cast\022': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 14: $'\001x\004SrcT\032\t\n\001y\004DstT\f\n\004SrcT\022\004type\f': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 15: $'\004DstT\022\004type': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 16: 8: command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 17: $'\005Const\032\017': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 18: $'\006output\005dtype\017': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 24: $'\005value\022\006tensor\r\n\005dtype\022\004type\n\354\001\n\006Conv2D\022\n\n\005input\001T\022\v': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 28: $'\006filter\001T\032\v\n\006output\001T\023\n\001T\022\004type:\b\n\0062\004\023\016\001\002\024': command not found <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 29: syntax error near unexpected token (' <path to .pb file>/saved_model.pb:
 line 29: strides�  list(int)"�'
```

I am not sure how to fix the issue.
I am using anaconda in my system.
Any lead would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model_base_path` should be a directory, the parent folder of the version folder of `saved_model.pb` and `variables\`, not a file. For example, for the following directory, `model_base_path` should be `path_to_versions\versions`.

```
`-- versions
    `-- 1
        |-- saved_model.pbtxt
        `-- variables
            |-- variables.data-00000-of-00001
            `-- variables.index
```

Comment: Thanks @Yiding. 
I made change accordingly and 'model_base_path' is now pointing to the directory containing the .pb file 
and the variables folder. 
However, this attempt also threw error.
command used (/serve/1 folder contains .pb file):
tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 --model_name=saved_model --model_base_path=$(<path to folder containing .pb file and variables folder>/CycleGAN-TensorFlow_v2/serve/1/) 

Please find below the new error:  
bash: <path to folder containing .pb file and variables folder>/CycleGAN-TensorFlow_v2/serve/1/: Is a directory
Illegal instruction